# How do I isolate Cities based on STATE JSON with LODASH and Angular 13

Tags: typescript, lodash, angular13

This is a little challenging but I'm almost there.

here's my abridged JSON object of all countries in the world with all it's cities.

The only exception is USA and CANADA where USA has states, which I'm getting and Canada has PROVINCES which I'm getting.

The JSON contains country-->cities

```
{
"data": {
    "Cape Verde": ["Praia"],
    "Cayman Islands": [
      "Coral Gables",
      "George Town",
      "West Bay",
      "Savannah",
      "Spot Bay",
      "Bodden Town",
      "Newlands"
    ],
    "Central African Republic": ["Bangui"],
    "Chad": ["Massaguet", "AbÃ©chÃ©", "N'Djamena", "Moundou"],
        "United States": [
      "Mukilteo",
      "Fairfield",
      "Chicago",
      "Hernando",
      "Irving",
      "Baltimore",
      "Kingston",
      "Burlington",
      "Harrison",
      "Newton Center",
      "Littleton"]
   }
}
```

I'm using TYPE AHEAD to populate the COUNTRIES, then for United States, I get the STATES but getting the CITIES for any specific state is a wee bit of a challenge.

Here's the CITY/STATE JSON https://medium.com/hackernoon/json-of-5-950-usa-cities-and-their-states-29352c40ad21

So, here's my code for what I'm doing currently which works.

```
  /**
   * @name getAllCountries
   * @description gets all countries
   * @returns Object
   */
  getAllCountries(): any {
    console.log('FILTERED ALL COUNTRIES: ', this.allCountries.data);
    return this.allCountries.data;
  }

  getStatesFromCountry(country: string): any {

    if (country === 'United States') {
      this.filteredstates = this.states.states;
    } else {
      this.filteredcities = this.getCitiesFromCountry(country);
    }

    console.log('FILTERED STATES: ', this.filteredstates);
    return this.filteredstates;
  }
```

This is the challenge using that NEW JSON object in the link from MEDIUM

```
  getCitiesFromState(state: string): any {
    const self = this;
    let cs = [];
    cs.push(this.allStatesAndCities);
    let cities: number[] = [];

    let ret = _.find(cs, function(value, key) {
      if (value === state) {
        cities.push(key);
      }
    })
    this.filteredcities = cities;
    // for (let i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
    //   if (cs[i] === state) {
    //     this.filteredcities = cs[i];
    //   }
    // }
    console.log('FILTERED STATES: ', this.filteredcities);
    return this.filteredcities;
  }
```

Here's my image of the DEV console.
[image: Image of Dev Console]

This is what part of the STATES --> CITIES which is the "value" in the image

```
{
  "New York": [
    "New York",
    "Buffalo",
    "Rochester",
    "Yonkers",
    "Syracuse",
    "Albany",
    "New Rochelle",
    "Mount Vernon",
    "Schenectady",
    "Utica",
    "White Plains",
    "Hempstead",
    "Troy",
    "Niagara Falls",
    "Binghamton",
    "Freeport",
    "Valley Stream"
  ],
  "California": [
    "Los Angeles",
    "San Diego",
    "San Jose",
    "San Francisco",
    "Fresno",
    "Sacramento",
...
```

Here's the JSON for the above
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ahmu83/38865147cf3727d221941a2ef8c22a77/raw/c647f74643c0b3f8407c28ddbb599e9f594365ca/US_States_and_Cities.json

Any help would be great... I'm essentially wanting to filter the cities when I send a STATE into the function and them SORTED A - Z.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
  getCitiesFromState(state: string): any {
    const self = this;
    let cs = this.allStatesAndCities[0];

    let cities = _.get(cs, state);  <<<<---- _.get worked

  console.log('FILTERED CITIES: ', this.filteredcities);
    return this.filteredcities;
  }
```